Getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error after migration to ant-design/charts v.2.2.1 and using {renderer: new SVGRenderer()} in chart config
I'm wondering if anybody else get the same error as I do after the migration to @ant-design/charts v.2.2.1 and, specifically, after the usage of { renderer: new SVGRenderer() } in chart config?
The old renderer (renderer: "svg") is not supported anymore. But the new one (renderer: new SVGRenderer()) crashes my app even for the simplest charts with the minimum of data to render.
Here's the full chart config for Line charts which I've implemented in my Chart component:
import { Renderer as SVGRenderer } from "@antv/g-svg";
// ...Other imports

// ... some code ...
if (type === ChartTypeEnum.COLUMN) {
      chartConfig = {
        data: chartData || [],
        height: 530,
        xField: "xField",
        yField: "yField",
        renderer: new SVGRenderer(),
        stack: {
          groupBy: "x",
          series: false,
        },
        colorField: "category",
        interaction: {
          tooltip: {
            render: (
              e: PlotEvent,
              {
                title,
                items,
              }: { title: string; items: { color: string; value: string }[] }
            ) => (
              <div>
                <b>{title}</b>
                <div>
                  {items.map(({ color, value }, grade) => (
                    <div
                      style={{
                        margin: 0,
                        display: "flex",
                        justifyContent: "space-between",
                      }}
                    >
                      <div>
                        <span
                          style={{
                            display: "inline-block",
                            width: 6,
                            height: 6,
                            borderRadius: "50%",
                            backgroundColor: color,
                            marginRight: 6,
                          }}
                        />
                        {grade + 1}
                      </div>
                      <b>{value}</b>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            ),
          },
        },
        xAxis: {
          title: {
            text: xAxisName,
            style: {
              fontSize: 12,
              fill: "#00203399",
            },
          },
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: "Распределение голосов",
            style: {
              fontSize: 12,
              fill: "#00203399",
              lineWidth: 20,
            },
          },
        },
        label: {
          position: "outside",
          style: {
            fill: "#FFFFFF",
            opacity: 0.6,
          },
        },
        legend: {
          offsetX: 8,
          position: "bottom-left",
          collapsed: true,
          marker: {
            symbol: "square",
          },
        },
        slider: {
          backgroundStyle: {
            fill: "#33ACF2",
            fillOpacity: 0.1,
          },
          foregroundStyle: {
            fill: "#33ACF2",
            fillOpacity: 1,
          },
          x: {},
        },
      } as ColumnConfig;
    }
// ... some code ...

If I comment out the line renderer: new SVGRenderer() in this config, everything works perfectly!
The error itself looks like this:

